# Реализовать процесс авторизации и регистрации программно

Tags: c#

Как правильно реализовать процесс регистрации и авторизации пользователя в программе на языке C#? Куда должен заноситься зарегистрированный пользователь и 
должна ли отображаться информация о пользователе в окне авторизации после данного процесса?

Comment: `Куда должен заноситься зарегистрированный пользователь?` скорее всего в базу данных. При авторизации делаете запрос к БД с целью проверить существуют ли такие логин и пароль в базе. При регистрации вставляете нужные данные. Это большая тема.

Comment: А куда хотите, туда и заносите. Хотите в user preferences, хотите в базу данных, хотите в текстовый файл. И отображать или нет — решать только вам.

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример для регистрации нового пользователя в локальную БД на Mysql :

```
    using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
    //....
    internal static void AddNewClient(string Name, string Login, string Pass )
    {
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            string query = @"insert into bdName.TableName() values(@name,@login ,@password); ";
            MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"name", Name);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"login", Login);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"password", Pass);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("New Client was successfully added!","");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.Source); // Лучше обработать все возможные исключения
            }
        }
    }
```

Строка подключения будет выглядеть примерно так :

```
    static string ConnectionString = "User Id=root;Password=root;Host=localhost;Database=DataBaaseName; port=3306;Charset=utf8;connection timeout = 15";
```

Для авторизации пишите запрос вроде :

```
   @"select * from  TableName where `Login` = 'log' and `Password` = 'pass'";
```

Если запрос вернул строки и пользователь с указанным логином и паролем есть в БД то открывайте главную форму или что там необходимо сделать.
Это только один из вариантов коих много. И база данных, как заметил @VlaD только один из них.

Comment: Вы осторожнее с добавлением, там же возможно SQL injection. Лучше добавлять через параметризированную команду.

Comment: @VladD да, я потом добавил про параметры.

Comment: Я имел в виду insert тоже. Там стоит тоже перейти на параметры.

Comment: @VladD Согласен. Поменял

Comment: Ага, так намного лучше, спасибо!